# Firebase for real time feature while keeping my own rest service and backend database?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have angular JS application that gets data from REST service with sql server backend. I develop and have control on all 3 parts - angular app, rest service and database.

I want to now add pizazz by making this app near real time by using Firebase. My question is - can I keep my current rest service and database for the most part and only use Firebase database and the library minimally and only where necessary to support real time?

Comment: yep you can do that. You can even have your rest server generate auth tokens for Firebase so you only have to manage sessions and users from one place.

Comment: @rob thank you that's really good to know. i will read documentation on firebase site to get started!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). This is possible because as you mention in your question, you control the REST service and the SQL server. Thus, because the server is trusted you can connect it to your Firebase database by authenticating it using a JWT.

As a result you can keep managing user accounts the way you currently do with the added "pizzaz" of making a subset of data available in "near real time". Firebase app JWTs can be generated with any existing JWT generation library and then signed by a SHA-256 HMAC signature.

**Authenticating Servers**

Because you are running a trusted server that is connecting your own Firebase database, you can authenticate it in several ways:

> 1. Using a Firebase app secret:  All authentication methods can accept a Firebase app secret instead of a JWT token. This will grant the
>      server complete read and write access to the entire Firebase database.
>      This access will never expire unless it is revoked via the App
>      Dashboard.
> 2. Using a secure JWT with the optional admin claim set to true:  This method will grant a server complete read and write access to the
>      entire Firebase database. This token will expire normally, so it is
>      important to set the expiration times accordingly.
> 3. Using a secure JWT designed to give access to only the pieces of data a server needs to touch:  This method is more complicated, but it
>      is the safest way to authenticate a server as it lets the Security and
>      Firebase Rules prevent the server from doing anything it's not
>      supposed to, even if it becomes compromised in some way.

Source: Firebase Documentation - 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html

**Generating Tokens**

There are Helper Libraries available for many platforms but for this example I will use the Firebase Token Generator for Node.js made available by Firebase.

Firebase Token Generator for Node.js:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node

Step 1:
Install the package using either npm or Bower (or compile from source).

Step 2: Copy the app secret from your Firebase instance's dashboard.

Step 3: Generate a token using Node.js by passing your Firebase app secret to the FirebaseTokenGenerator constructor method like this:

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({uid: "1", some: "arbitrary", data: "here"});
```

Comment: thanks @dmax for the detailed info which I will be certain to use in near future. I will update this post how things went.

Comment: no problem, @SamDevx! This is the first answer I've ever posted to SO and any feedback or suggestions on how to improve it would be much appreciated. Looking forward to hearing how it worked out for you.